# How to get value of model in wicket behavior

Tags: java, wicket

in my form I have input text and then dataView:

```
private class RegistrationForm extends Form<Table> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RegistrationForm(final Table table) {
        super("registrationForm", new CompoundPropertyModel<Table>(table));
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        final TextField<String> text = new TextField<String>("name");
        add(text);
        DataView<Player> dataView = new DataView<Player>("rows", playerDataProvider) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final Item<Player> listItem) {
...
```

on listItem I add ajaxEventBehavior when I double Click on row:

```
                listItem.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("ondblclick") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    protected void onEvent(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                            System.out.println(table.getName());

                     }
                });
```

Problem is when I double click on table it print null not the value which I have in input TextField. Why ?

I try to update model:

```
                            text.updateModel();
```

or get value from text:

```
                            System.out.println(table.getName() + "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" + text.getInput() + "vv"
                                    + text.getValue() + "ff");
```

but with no success.

in form I have also submit button and when I press it every think works. I have problems just with double click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AjaxEventBehavior` itself does not submit the form, so you're not getting the text field value. You can use one of the following subclasses instead:

- `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` will submit only the one `FormComponent` it is attached to. It needs to be attached to a FormComponent, so you'll have to use the following if you want to attach it to the entire `ListItem`:
- `AjaxFormSubmitBehavior` will submit the entire form. This is probably what you need here.

All these behaviors are included in Wicket and their Javadoc is right there with the source code. For the Ajax stuff, check subclasses of `AbstractAjaxBehavior`, in particular the subclasses of `AjaxEventBehavior`.

Comment: I try this but this behaviors doesnt invoke when I double click on table

Comment: btw AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior cannot be add to listItem because of this exception: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Behavior can only be added to an instance of a FormComponent

Comment: btw can you give me some links where is documnted all wicket behaviors ? Because i didint find it on google

Comment: edited the answer to clarify. Check the Javadoc and AjaxEventBehavior's subclasses.

Comment: there is a just few information. I need to know what event I can set into behavior as paramater like onChange ...

Comment: The events are the standard browser javascript events - onclick, ondblclick, onfocus, etc. Look at any kind of javascript documentation to find them.